# Regex capturing inserted variables in PHP SQL string statements

Tags: php, python, regex

I'm having some regex troubles, using Python 2.7 if that matters.

Basically what I'm trying to do is to capture inserted variables in a PHP SQL query string declaration, for example:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user='$user' AND password='$pass';";
```

This should return `$user` when I get the second group from the match.

Here's my regex as it stands right now:

```
r'.*?\s*=\s*\(\".*?\'(\$[^\']+)\'.*?\"\);'
```

[Example showing that this works and captures `$user` but not the one above (yes I know it doesn't capture $pass as it ideally should, that's seems to be a limitation with Python's implementation and Regex in general. I do some hacks to get around this in my actual program)](http://pythex.org/?regex=.*%3F%5Cs*%3D%5Cs*%5B%5C(%5D%3F%5C%22.*%3F%5C%27(%5C%24%5B%5E%5C%27%5D%2B)%5C%27.*%3F%5C%22%5B%5C)%5D%3F%3B&test_string=%24query%20%3D%20(%22SELECT%20table_schema%2C%20table_name%2C%20create_time%20FROM%20information_schema.tables%20WHERE%20table_schema%3D%27%7B%24_DVWA%5B%27db_database%27%5D%7D%27%20AND%20table_name%3D%27users%27%20LIMIT%201%22)%3B%0A%24query1%20%3D%20%22SELECT%20*%20FROM%20%60users%60%20WHERE%20user%3D%27%24user%27%20AND%20password%3D%27%24pass%27%3B%22%3B&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

The above works for the example I used. However, when I introduce another case where the inserted variable uses the syntax `'{$foo['bar']}'`, my other regex below doesn't work which accounts for the fact that it contains an apostrophe which doesn't close the variable:

```
r'.*?\s*=\s*[\(]?\".*?(?:(?:\'(\$[^\']+)\')|(?:\'(\$\{[^\}]+\})\'))?.*?\"[\)]?;'
```

So basically I want to capture either the `'$user`' syntax or the one with { }, for example `'{$foo['bar']}'`. Note that these are not exclusive, it's just that an inserted variable may be of either kind and I want to account for both.

[Here's a link to test this out, showing that it doesn't work. Using the second regex also breaks capturing the simple `$user`, not sure why.](http://pythex.org/?regex=.*%3F%5Cs*%3D%5Cs*%5B%5C(%5D%3F%5C%22.*%3F(%3F%3A(%3F%3A%5C%27(%5C%24%5B%5E%5C%27%5D%2B)%5C%27)%7C(%3F%3A%5C%27(%5C%24%5C%7B%5B%5E%5C%7D%5D%2B%5C%7D)%5C%27))%3F.*%3F%5C%22%5B%5C)%5D%3F%3B&test_string=%24query%20%3D%20(%22SELECT%20table_schema%2C%20table_name%2C%20create_time%20FROM%20information_schema.tables%20WHERE%20table_schema%3D%27%7B%24_DVWA%5B%27db_database%27%5D%7D%27%20AND%20table_name%3D%27users%27%20LIMIT%201%22)%3B%0A%24query1%20%3D%20%22SELECT%20*%20FROM%20%60users%60%20WHERE%20user%3D%27%24user%27%20AND%20password%3D%27%24pass%27%3B%22%3B&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: Why in the world do you want to parse mysql query using regex? I hope it's not for some kind of injection protection.

Comment: Yes it sort of is. It's for a school project where we want to see how much of GitHub code is not secured using the very basic PHP injection protections such as prepared statements or escaped strings. Therefore we need to search a lot of code, I thought regex was the best option.

Comment: This sound interesting (cool school project) yet quite difficult. Regex is indeed one option to do it but will never offer a complete solution. For highly complex code it's impossible to determine the control flow of the program. So there might be no actual protection where the queries are executed. It might already happened long before. Another option would be to create an ast tree of the code, this should be easier to search. This is a whole bunch of work but might deliver better results than regex.

Comment: I thought of using parse trees, but it would require too much work. The project is not supposed to completely cover all cases, just give a pointer of how the situation of open source code is.

Comment: You're right, it would be a lot of work. I'm sure you can get some nice results with you approach too. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what do you mean by limitation in python because following works as it should:

```
>>> import re
>>> query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user='$user' AND password='$pass';";
>>> re.findall(r"='(\$\w+)'", query)
['$user', '$pass']
```

For matching the other query have a look at this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lI6pA3/2):

```
='(\{?\$.+?)(?:'(?:\s|;))
```

And, code example:

```
>>> query1 = "(\"SELECT table_schema, table_name, create_time FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='{$_DVWA['db_database']}' AND table_name='users' LIMIT 1\");"
>>> re.findall(r"='(\{?\$.+?)(?:'(?:\s|;))", query1)
["{$_DVWA['db_database']}"]

# it works on the other query as well
>>> re.findall(r"='(\{?\$.+?)(?:'(?:\s|;))", query)
['$user', '$pass']
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about this technique. I thought findall only returned match objects which would mean I had to search them again. Thanks! However, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Works amazingly. Thanks!